TeX variables become local within list environments?
Apparently, when the value of a TeX counter is modified inside an enumerate environment (and no doubt many other contexts), it acts like a local variable, so that any modifications to it are local to the environnent.  For example, this code
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\total
\total = 5

\begin{document}

At first total = \number\total

\begin{enumerate}
\item \advance \total by 10
      Now total = \number\total
\item \advance \total by 10
      Now total = \number\total
\end{enumerate}

Outside of the enumerate environment, total reverts to its
original value: \number\total\\

Does the same thing happen in embedded environments?
\begin{enumerate}
\item \advance \total by 100
      Now total = \number\total
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item \advance \total by 1000
      Now total = \number\total
      \end{enumerate}
      That didn't do anything to this total = \number\total
\item \advance \total by 100
      Now total = \number\total
\end{enumerate}
Yes.  Now total = \number\total

\end{document}

produces:

Two questions:

How should I understand what's going on here?
What is the simplest way to story modify a value inside an enumerate environment so that the modified value is available outside of the environment? I'm fine with using LaTeX rather than TeX facilities here. I just want a simple solution that works.

Why? I'm writing a test, and for each question, I specify the number of points it's worth.  When I display the points, I also want to update a variable that will give me a total at the end.  Sometimes I assign points to sub-questions that I list in an embedded environment.  I want those points added to the total as well.
At present, I do it like this:
\newcount\totalpts
\totalpts = 0
\newcommand{\pts}[1]{(#1 points) \advance \totalpts by #1}

and I use the \pts command to display the number of points for each question.  It works if I only use one enumerate environment to display questions, because I can display the total as part of the last question.  It doesn't work if I assign points in an enumerate environment that's embedded in the outer questions environment: the points I list for questions in the embedded environment don't affect the total in the outer environment.
Of course, feel free to point me to earlier questions.  I feel certain that this kind of question must have been discussed in tex.SE previously, but I can't figure out a strategy for searching for it.
1

All assignments are local by default (there are a few special TeX registers were is an exception). It means that if a TeX group ends then the register returns to its previous value valid when the group starts.
If you use the \global prefix of the assignment, then the assignment is global, its value will kept when the TeX group ends.
So, use \global\advance instead \advance or define \def\gadvance{\global\advance} and use \gadvance instead \advance when you are working with the \total register. And use direct assignment \global\total=value if it is in a TeX group.

Perfect. Thanks!  TeX is such a weird language.  (That doesn't say anything new. Nor am I disparaging Knuth in any way.)

As wipet explained, assignments to TeX count registers are local to the current group. All LaTeX environments create groups. This includes list environments, but you would see the same effect if you advanced the count inside figure, center, quotation etc.
While direct assignments to count registers are local by default, LaTeX counters assign globally. So, if you use a counter and \addtocounter{}{}, the assignments to the underlying count register will be made globally and persist outside the current group.
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{total}
\setcounter{total}{5}

\begin{document}

At first total = \thetotal

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \addtocounter{total}{10}
  Now total = \thetotal
  \item \addtocounter{total}{10}
  Now total = \thetotal
\end{enumerate}

Outside of the enumerate environment, total reverts to its
original value: \thetotal % never end a paragraph with \\

Does the same thing happen in embedded environments?
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \addtocounter{total}{100}
  Now total = \thetotal
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \addtocounter{total}{1000}
    Now total = \thetotal
  \end{enumerate}
  That didn't do anything to this total = \thetotal
  \item \addtocounter{total}{100}
  Now total = \thetotal
\end{enumerate}
Yes.  Now total = \thetotal

\end{document}

With this solution, you can also redefine \thetotal to modify the formatting, in just the same way you can modify the appearance of section numbers, footnotes, equation numbers etc. This is why it is better to use \thetotal than to write \arabic{total} directly, even though these would currently produce the same result.


Thanks very much cfr!  I could only accept one answer, so I accepted @wipet's because it answered the question that I literally asked, but your answer answers a question that I also wanted to know about: how can I do this in LaTeX per se without a lot of complication.

@Mars As I read your question, wipet answered both parts (why? how?) and I slightly expanded one (why?) but mostly answered the other (how?). Since you explicitly asked for solutions whether LaTeX or otherwise, you got multiple answers. That's not uncommon on this site and everyone knows you can only answer one. I'm glad you accepted wipet's. As a non-LaTeX user, it's only fair wipet should get a tick when the OP is using plain!
